# Why is plugin of eband_local_planner named bgp_plugin.xml?

Tags: ros, plugin, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that a plugin name of eband_local_planner is bgp_plugin.xml. Eband_local_planner is a kind of like local_planner. Why is the plugin named bgp_plugin.xml instead of blp_plugin.xml? Actually, if I rename bgp_plugin.xml to blp_plugin.xml, Errors happened.
Does anybody know the reason?

```
[ERROR] [1400628392.643232931]: Skipping XML Document "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/eband_local_planner/bgp_plugin.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
[ERROR] [1400628392.761079585]: Skipping XML Document "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/eband_local_planner/bgp_plugin.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
[ERROR] [1400628392.880693695]: Skipping XML Document "/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/eband_local_planner/bgp_plugin.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
[ INFO] [1400628394.619906326]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1400628394.719745267]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1400628394.886922629]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1400628395.115048446]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1400628395.654797784]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1400628395.674817370]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1400628395.701033172]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan bump
[ INFO] [1400628395.861715994]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1400628396.344856710]: Loading from pre-hydro parameter style
[ INFO] [1400628396.474822909]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1400628396.646287882]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan bump
[ INFO] [1400628396.803163198]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[FATAL] [1400628396.933781606]: Failed to create the eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS with base class type nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS pose_follower/PoseFollower
[move_base-5] process has died [pid 13705, exit code 1, cmd /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel __name:=move_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e406e8be-e075-11e3-b207-dc85de8a0cd2/move_base-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/e406e8be-e075-11e3-b207-dc85de8a0cd2/move_base-5*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167471/why-is-plugin-of-eband_local_planner-named-bgp_plugin.xml?/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The name of the xml file that defines the plugins doesn't matter; it just has to match between the package's package.xml and the filename.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-20**:
Thanks, @ahendrix: I wanna ask you one more question. I think that move_base calls bgp_plugin.xml and blp_plugin.xml. In this case, move_base can't call other global_planner. I think so.  Is this idea wrong?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-20**:
No. The name of the file is not related to how move_base interprets it, and it shouldn't prevent you from loading other global planners.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-20**:
Thanks, @ahendrix: Actually, I check that default global planner(global_planner/GlobalPlanner) is called.